# Updating a column of large Postgres table efficiently with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-update, query-optimization, psycopg2

I want to update a certain column of a large table in a remotely connected Postgres database. I'm running a forloop in python, with each of the loop running cursor.execute() to run the update query that looks something like this: "`UPDATE db.table SET col = %s WHERE key = %s`". However, with about 12 million rows in the table, to go through each row, and execute the query each time, it takes too much time (estimated about a few thousand hours). Is there a way to drastically speed this up?

Comment: What are the rules for the new value for `col`? Can it be derived from key or from other columns in the row or does it come from an external table? Generally, you should try to do it in SQL rather than in python.

Comment: It comes from an external source, as the code essentially does some data manipulation in python to generate a value that goes into col before updating the table

Comment: What kind of functions or manipulations? Can it be written as SQL?

Comment: 1) Use [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers), though that will still take some time 2) Use `psycopg2` [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) support and `COPY` the column data to a staging table and then do `UPDATE db.table select col from staging_table where key = staging_table.key`.

Comment: The docs (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html) have an example of using execute_values to do a bulk update.